# Keep Django runserver alive when SSH is closed

Tags: python, django, ssh, server

I haven't yet been able to get Apache working with my Django app, so until I do get it working, I'm using runserver on my Linux server in order to demo the app. The problem is that whenever I close the SSH connection to the server, runserver stops running. How can I keep runserver running when I say put my laptop to sleep, or lose internet connectivity?

P.S. I'm aware that runserver isn't intended for production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since runserver isn't intended to be ran in production/only for development there is no way to to this built in.

You will need to use a tool like `tmux`/`screen` or `nohup` to keep the process alive, even if the spawning terminal closes.

Answer (score 12):

#### Using Screen

You can run `runserver` in a [screen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen) session. After you detach from that session it will keep running. Login via ssh and start a screen session via

```
screen
```

It will look like your usual terminal. Now, run the server

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

After this, you can detach from the session using `Ctrl+a Ctrl+d`. Now your app should be available even after you quit your ssh session.

If you want to cancel the `runserver`, you can re-atach to your screen session. Get a list of existing sessions with

```
screen -ls

There is a screen on:
    10989.pts-1.hostname (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screens/S-username.
```

Then, you can reatach with the command

```
screen -R 10989
```

#### Using nohup

Again, after login into your server, start the runserver with

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 8080 &
```

All output the `runserver` writes (like debug info and so on) will be written to a file called `nohup.out` in the same folder.

To quit the server after using `nohup` you need to keep the process id (pid) shown or find the `pid` afterwards with `ps`, `top` or any other tool.

Comment: ```nohup python manage.py runserver 8080 &``` worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ nohup python manage.py runserver &
```

`nohup` makes command ignore hangup signal and `&` puts in to background disconnecting from stdout

Answer (score 1):

If you are SSH'ing through to your server and starting Django there, consider use of a program on the server such as [`tmux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). This will allow your server-side shell process to remain alive after disconnection, and you can reattach on your next login with a simple

```
tmux attach
```

command.